# Remove all HTML others than button inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove all the content (created dynamically) from a DIV but not a button that exists by default. This is the HTML:

```
<div id="{{ entity.getLabel|lower ~ "_choice_" ~ entity.getId }}" style="display: none">
    <button type="button" class="add-size">Adicionar {{ entity.getLabel|lower }}</button>
</div>
```

And I'm doing as follow:

```
$("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).empty();
$("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).hide();
```

Of course the vars takes their proper values I just tough `.empty()` removes all and I need to leave the button, how I do that?

PS: In both cases HTML and jQuery code forget about vars and Twig tags since it does the job I just need to replace `$.empty()` for some working code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':not(button)').remove();
```

Comment: Why not just `$("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID + ' :not(button)').remove()`

Comment: @Itay just because .find() will be a little faster but nothing noticeable and i find it more readable

Comment: Really? Didn't know that. Can you give me some source to read about it?

Comment: @Itay best reading would be jquery source code, using .find() internally to handle some selector. But now as for modern browser it is using querySelectorAll(), it doesn't really matter, but still: http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector/36