# Insert element before button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on the aswer that a user give me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747940/remove-all-html-others-than-button-inside-a-div/18747990) I try to build my code to insert some HTML code before a button and I'm doing this:

```
$("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':button').before().append(input);
```

But it inserts the code inside the button tag and not before the button element, what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing the input is what you want to insert, use this:

```
  $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':button').before(input);
```

[before documentation](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Answer (score 4):

`.before()` inserts content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

Try:

```
 $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':button').before(input);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr3Da/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `prev` to append element on it

```
 $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':button').prev(input);
```

[`Prev Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle - there seems to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jQuery's `before()` method. It inserts element before each element in the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/before/